# Elementary eigenspaces shared by square matrices that commute

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional linear space over the complex numbers, and $A$ and $B$ mapping $X$ to itself, which commute: $AB=BA$.

Show that $A$ and $B$ share the same elementary eigenspaces.

Given the context of the question, I think the answer will relate to the null-space of $(A - aI)^{k}$, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Suppose $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ for matrix $A$.  Then $A(Bx) = B(Ax) = B(\lambda x) = \lambda (Bx)$.  Now, notice that $Bx$ is then an eigenvector of $A$ in the same eigenspace as $x$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Under what conditions does this hold? For example, does this work if some eigenvalues have multiplicity $>1$? Because the original problem that I was looking at doesn't assume any conditions like that.